# How can I output this table with indexes in latex?

Tags: latex

How can I outputthis table exactly like that in LaTeX?

[image]

I'm using the latest versions of WindEdt and LaTeX.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to reproduce exactly the same, as simply as possible.

The code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & %
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }\\
\cline{1-5}
\textbf{12} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{7} & X3\\
\cline{1-5}
\textbf{11} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{5} & 0 & \textbf{5} & X1\\
\cline{1-5}
7 & 9 & 9 & 6 & \textbf{0} & \\
\cline{1-5}
\textbf{0} & 3 & 10 & \textit{13} & 9 & \\
\cline{1-5}
5 & \textbf{0} & 0 & \textit{4} & 9 & \\
\cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

Don't hesitate to comment if you need further explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `tabular` with 6 columns and the command `\multicolumn` to control vertical bars:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X2} \\
  \cline{1-5}
  12 & 9 & 4 & 0 & 7 & X3\\
  \cline{1-5}
  % and so on ...
\end{tabular}
```